# Adding data to SQL not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am currently learning SQL and have created this code for a few hours but I am unable to add data to my SQL server. Below I have provided a minimum working example of an input field and submit to SQL server. Any help is greatly appreciated. (I removed the password). I believe the problem is with isset($_POST['submit'] or before this point as the server does not seem to acknowledge the rest.

With thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="dd" width="100%" id="data">
    <td>Field</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td width="17%"><input type='textarea' name='field'/></td>
</table>
<input name='submit' type='submit'  value='submit'/>

<?php

// Setting up the Database Connection
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "table_name";
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password);

@mysqli_select_db($dbname);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $field = isset ($_POST['field']);
    $field_f = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
    $que = "INSERT INTO table_test ('fieldsql') VALUES ('$field_f')";
    mysqli_query($que);

if (mysqli_query($link,$que) === TRUE) {
echo "Record added successfully";
    }} 
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to use `form` tag

Comment: Also, the column name `fieldsql` should not be enclosed in single quotes.  In SQL Server, identifiers should be enclosed in double-quotes or square brackets, or not enclosed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `form` in your html. Without `form` tag your `textarea` and `submit` button wont work.

Try this :

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table class="dd" width="100%" id="data">
    <td>Field</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td width="17%"><input type='textarea' name='field'/></td>
</table>
<input name='submit' type='submit'  value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Also your query is wrong. Please use following query :

```
"INSERT INTO table_test (fieldsql) VALUES ('$field_f')";
```

> Side note : Your query is unsafe. Read this
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: In addition I think his insert query is not correct (insert into table (field)) and not insert into table('field')